# Failed to delete Windows Azure web hosting plan

Tags: azure

I have followed the instructions here - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/.  I have emptied the web hosting plan, I can't delete the websites as they are live, so I have moved them to another web hosting plan.  When I try to delete the hosting plan I get the following error;

Failed to delete web hosting plan : There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.

I have waited over an hour now, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to remove the additional web hosting plan. If you delete the last website in a hosting plan, Windows Azure deletes the hosting plan. I couldn't specifically delete an empty hosting plan, which is a bit stupid, but deleting the final website in the hosting plan has the same effect.

Comment: I deleted every websites under a WebHostingPlan, but the hosting plan didn't delete itself. Now I cannot do anything on it, any idea how I could clean this up?